# Android ORMlite SelectArg

Tags: android, ormlite

I've read a few things on using the SelectArg on stackoverflow and the ORMLite documentation and i can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm searching the occupations table where the job field = "Athletes' Business Manager". As you can see it contains a single quote which I'm trying to escape using a SelectArg.

```
SelectArg occupationArg = new SelectArg(txtOccupation.getText().toString().trim());

Occupations occupation = CommonUtilities.getHelper(getApplicationContext()).getOccupationsDao().queryBuilder().where().eq(
                 Occupations.JOB_FIELD, occupationArg).queryForFirst();
```

The above code gives me the following error:

Unable to load driver details: SQL ex: Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `occupations` WHERE `job` = 'Athletes' Business Manager'

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling for a while with similar problem and finally found correct implementation:

```
Dao<Book, Integer> bookDao = getDatabaseHelper(ctx).getBookDao();
UpdateBuilder<Book, Integer> builder = bookDao.updateBuilder();
builder.updateColumnValue("title", book.getTitle());
SelectArg titleArg = new SelectArg();
titleArg.setValue(book.getTitle());
builder.updateColumnValue("title", titleArg);
...
PreparedUpdate<Book> prepare = (PreparedUpdate<Book>) builder.where().idEq(book.getIdField()).prepare();
bookDao.update(prepare);
```

So in your case pass the value via setValue method, instead of constructor:

```
SelectArg occupationArg = new SelectArg(txtOccupation.getText().toString().trim());
```